# rsyslog omfwd-tcp stops sending after some time

Tags: rsyslog

I have an rsyslog that should just forward messages. It has the regular 514-UDP Port open and receives messages. Forwarding to omfwd-tcp works for a while and than stops.

```
 if $syslogfacility != 1 then {
  action(Name="syslog-fwd" Type="omfwd" Target="127.0.0.1" Port="10514" >template="JSONDefaultstr" Action.ResumeInterval="5" Protocol="tcp")
stop
}
```

In the log i can see the following:

```
2093.110977082:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: wti 0x55e240948920: wti.c: worker awoke from idle processing
2093.110980024:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: queue.c: DeleteProcessedBatch: we deleted 0 objects and enqueued 0 objects
2093.110982399:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: queue.c: doDeleteBatch: delete batch from store, new sizes: log 1, phys 1
2093.110984879:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: syslog-fwd queue: queue.c: dequeued 1 consumable elements, szlog 0 sz phys 1
2093.110991750:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: action 'syslog-fwd': is transactional - executing in commit phase
2093.110994557:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: omfwd.c: omfwd: beginTransaction
2093.110997258:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: omfwd.c: omfwd: doTryResume 127.0.0.1 iRet 0
2093.110999651:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: action[syslog-fwd] transitioned to state: itx
2093.111002109:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: processBatchMain: i 0, processMsgMain iRet -2121
2093.111004393:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: processBatchMain: i 0, COMM state set
2093.111006850:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: actionCommit[syslog-fwd]: enter, 1 msgs
2093.111009128:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: actionCommit[syslog-fwd]: processing...
2093.111011368:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: actionTryCommit[syslog-fwd] enter
2093.111013724:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: doTransaction: have commitTransaction IF, using that, pWrkrInfo 0x55e2409489f0
2093.111016211:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: entering actionCallCommitTransaction[syslog-fwd], state: itx, nMsgs 1
2093.111018502:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: omfwd.c: omfwd: doTryResume 127.0.0.1 iRet 0
2093.111020942:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: omfwd.c:  127.0.0.1:10514/tcp
2093.111024094:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: omfwd.c: omfwd: add 227 bytes to send buffer (curr offs 0)
2093.111047664:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: omfwd.c: omfwd: TCP sent 227 bytes, requested 227
2093.111051182:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: actionCallCommitTransaction[syslog-fwd] state: itx mod commitTransaction returned 0
2093.111053587:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: action[syslog-fwd] transitioned to state: rdy
2093.111055999:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: actionCommit[syslog-fwd]: return actionTryCommit 0
2093.111058371:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: ../action.c: actionCommit[syslog-fwd]: done, iRet 0
2093.111060964:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: queue.c: regular consumer finished, iret=0, szlog 0 sz phys 1
2093.111063484:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: queue.c: DeleteProcessedBatch: etry 0 state 3
2093.111066649:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: queue.c: DeleteProcessedBatch: we deleted 1 objects and enqueued 0 objects
2093.111069152:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: queue.c: doDeleteBatch: delete batch from store, new sizes: log 0, phys 0
2093.111071641:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: syslog-fwd queue: queue.c: dequeued 0 consumable elements, szlog 0 sz phys 0
2093.111074225:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: queue.c: regular consumer finished, iret=4, szlog 0 sz phys 0
2093.111076514:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: wti.c: syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: worker IDLE, waiting for work.
2093.280167252:imtcp.c        : nsdpoll_ptcp.c: epoll returned 1 entries
2093.280182600:imtcp.c        : tcpsrv.c: tcpsrv: ready to process 1 event entries
...
```

this works fine... but than suddenly:

```
2093.280485033:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: wti 0x55e240948920: wti.c: worker awoke from idle processing
2093.280488998:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: queue.c: DeleteProcessedBatch: we deleted 0 objects and enqueued 0 objects
2093.280491486:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: queue.c: doDeleteBatch: delete batch from store, new sizes: log 2, phys 2
2093.280494077:syslog-fwd queue:Reg/w0: syslog-fwd queue: queue.c: dequeued 2 consumable elements, szlog 0 sz phys 2
2093.293312843:imtcp.c        : nsdpoll_ptcp.c: epoll returned 1 entries
2093.293326156:imtcp.c        : tcpsrv.c: tcpsrv: ready to process 1 event entries
```

And than "wti 0x55e240948920: wti.c: worker awoke from idle processing" never come up again.
Queue get filled:

```
2094.037943773:main Q:Reg/w0  : ../action.c: action 'syslog-fwd': called, logging to builtin:omfwd (susp 0/0, direct q 0)
2094.037946442:main Q:Reg/w0  : syslog-fwd queue: queue.c: qqueueAdd: entry added, size now log 11, phys 13 entries
2094.037948880:main Q:Reg/w0  : syslog-fwd queue: queue.c: EnqueueMsg advised worker start
2094.037951334:main Q:Reg/w0  : ../action.c: action 'syslog-fwd': set suspended state to 0
```

...

```
2363.077252235:main Q:Reg/w0  : ../action.c: action 'syslog-fwd': called, logging to builtin:omfwd (susp 0/0, direct q 0)
2363.077255829:main Q:Reg/w0  : syslog-fwd queue: queue.c: queue nearly full (3000 entries), but could not drop msg (iRet: 0, severity 6)
2363.077258619:main Q:Reg/w0  : syslog-fwd queue: queue.c: doEnqSingleObject: queue FULL - waiting 2000ms to drain.
```

And now the funny part: When I add the following rule (before the other)

```
if $syslogfacility == 4 then {
        action(Name="write4" Type="omfile" File="/var/log/syslog4" )
        stop
}
```

Everything works fine. Messages in

```
Oct 31 07:54:26 otherhost.com sssd_be: GSSAPI client step 2
Oct 31 07:54:27 somehost.com sssd_be: GSSAPI client step 1
```

Anybody with an hint?

Comment: What version of rsyslog are you using and what platform?

In your quoted config you have  >template=, is that a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: Centos with rsyslog-8.38.0-1.el7.x86_64 running on a vmware vm. That ">" is indeed a copy&paste mistake. Config works. And its maybe really an "platform" problem because it works on a bare-metal host. Anyway, strange problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've observed the same issue myself and have raised it as a bug:

https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/3273

In my case it was not related to omfwd as I sent using omrelp, instead it is imfile that causes the issue.